# How to create array of objects from 2 other array of objects with like values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here are 2 example arrays:

```
const inputData = [
    {
        ID: "2",
        Title: "Updated",
        ApprovedNamed: undefined,
    },
    {
        ID: "3",
        Title: "Update Title",
        ApprovedNamed: undefined,
    },
    {
        ID: "4",
        Title: "Item Four",
        ApprovedNamed: undefined,
    },
];

const currentData = [
    {
        ID: "1",
        Title: "Item One",
        ApprovedNamed: undefined,
    },
    {
        ID: "2",
        Title: "Item Two",
        ApprovedNamed: undefined,
    },
    {
        ID: "3",
        Title: "Item Three",
        ApprovedNamed: undefined,
    },
];
```

I am trying to build a new array of objects by comparing the inputData to currentData. If currentData contains an ID of any of inputData IDs then we make an array of `const updateData` and if it's new IDs (they aren't in currentData) then we make an array of `const newData`.

I tried this:
`const updateData = inputData.map((row) => currentData.find((o) => o.ID=== row.ID));`

but it fills updateData with everything regardless.

what should be happening based on the above data is:
updateData should have the objects for 2 and 3, while newData should have the object for ID 4 since it's not in currentData.

Comment: How is `.map()` supposed to magically "return" two new arrays? And no _"but it fills updateData with everything regardless"_, that's not true. `updateData` has `ID: 2` and `ID: 3` (and `undefined`, because that's how `.map()` works): https://jsfiddle.net/1dy7c4xt/

Comment: Use a plain old `for` loop and fill the two expected arrays "by hand", or use two `.filter()` calls, or `.reduce()`, or `.forEach()`, ...

Comment: @Andreas yeah you are right, I don't know why I thought it would just fill it out with .map. I'm over thinking it way too much apparently.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this:

```
 // create a dictionary of inputs to leverage inbuild hashmap
let inputDic = inputData.reduce((dic,input) => {
  dic[input.ID] = true;
  return dic;
}, {});

let newArr = [], updatedArr = [];

// loop over all the existing assuming current will always have all existing inputData
currentData.forEach(current => {
  if(inputDic[current.ID]){
    updatedArr.push(current);
  } else {
    newArr.push(current);
  }
});
console.log(newArr,updatedArr);
```